# Twig array access

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

I'm trying to print out value of the variable passed to the twig template. I'm using this code:

`{{ naziv[0] }}`  Index is 0 because passed array has only one element. Mentioned code produces following error:

> Key "0" for array with keys "title" does not exist in...

but when I use for loop like this:

```
{% for key,value in naziv %}
{{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get what I want.

What's wrong with `{{naziv[0]}}` ?

Comment: what does `{{ dump(naziv) }}` get you?

Comment: `array(1) { ["title"]=> string(11) "SpaceVision" }`

Comment: Your array is not number indexed, thus `naziv[0]` is not defined.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Based on the `var_dump` of `array(1) { ["title"]=> string(11) "SpaceVision" }`

You should access your array in this way: `{{ naziv['title'] }}`.

The key of your array is associative and not a numerically indexed array. That is why you cannot use `naziv[0]`.

You can also use: `{{ naziv.title }}` aswell.

See the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables).

Comment: thank you it helped, i had somesort of different problem but your variable['keyname'] method helped me.

Answer (score 5):

Your array is not number indexed, thus `naziv[0]` is not defined. Access it as `naziv.title`.