# How to pull a value out a or multi dimensional array using twig

Tags: arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array, twig

I am working on a test project to learn symfony2/twig. All I want to do is display a list of images, determined by a location.

I am retrieving data for these images from Instagram's API. The API sends back JSON data. For each image there is a wealth of information. I just need the low_resolution values to place in image tag.

I know how to transverse the data using standard PHP. However, I have no idea how to do this using TWIG. I just want to display the low_resolution url in an image tag. The closet I got was the following:

```html
{% if images_array == true %}
        {% for key,value in images_array %}
            {{ value.link }}

            {% for key,value in value.images %}
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="{{ value.url }}" alt="" class="thumbnail img-responsive" />                   
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

The problem with the above is that it loops through all the [url] in the [images] instead of displaying the value from [low_resolution]

Below is the first index of the data being brought in from Instagram.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attribution] => 
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => dubai
                )

            [location] => Array
                (
                    [latitude] => -29.854119007
                    [name] => ICC Durban Exhibition Centre,Durban,South Africa
                    [longitude] => 31.029556697
                    [id] => 450025614
                )

            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 0
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [filter] => Normal
            [created_time] => 1442931165
            [link] => https://instagram.com/p/775BhjE1kn/
            [likes] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 0
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [images] => Array
                (
                    [low_resolution] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11887246_500339553458410_480642133_n.jpg
                            [width] => 320
                            [height] => 320
                        )

                    [thumbnail] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/11887246_500339553458410_480642133_n.jpg
                            [width] => 150
                            [height] => 150
                        )

                    [standard_resolution] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11887246_500339553458410_480642133_n.jpg
                            [width] => 640
                            [height] => 640
                        )

                )

            [users_in_photo] => Array
                (
                )

            [caption] => Array
                (
                    [created_time] => 1442931165
                    [text] => Crecimiento importante a nivel Turistico y aeroportuario en #Dubai
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [username] => joseantonio1977
                            [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-19/11261324_916468171759729_1477908664_a.jpg
                            [id] => 194601237
                            [full_name] => Jose Antonio Lopez Sosa
                        )

                    [id] => 1079707331921664292
                )

            [type] => image
            [id] => 1079707329077926183_194601237
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [username] => joseantonio1977
                    [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-19/11261324_916468171759729_1477908664_a.jpg
                    [id] => 194601237
                    [full_name] => Jose Antonio Lopez Sosa
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this :

```
    {% for key,value in value.images %}
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="{{ value.url }}" alt="" class="thumbnail img-responsive" />                   
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

by:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="{{ value.images.low_resolution.url }}" alt="" class="thumbnail img-responsive" />                 
    </div>
```

Be sure not to use twice `key` and `value` variables for multiple loops

Based on another stackoverflow answer, here's how to navigate in an associative array in TWIG: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14199125/684101

Comment: Hi CoachNono, I tried your suggestion but received the following error message: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in default/geogram.html.twig at line 17.

Comment: Try the new code, without the parenthesis and only the call to image, I'm not sure of the exact syntax out of the blue, but I believe the first error was due to having key and value defined twice

Comment: That returned all 3 versions of the images just like my code. Where can I find proper documentation on this. I can only find the following page: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html which does not cover multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: Oh I get what was your question you don't want all three, only low_resolution right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90338/discussion-between-developer1-and-coachnono).